# SVN Import error messages

Tags: svn

Ive new to SVN and getting error messages when importing.

I've used a SO answer to import my source into my respository. But I cant get it to work.

The command is:
 svn import myrepos file:///c:/java/workspace/myDir -m "Initial import"

Error messages Im getting are:
svn: E180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///c:/java/workspace/myDir'

I must admit that I have NO idea what Im doing, so ...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
svn import C:\sourcedir http://svn.location -m "your message"
```

Man Page: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.import.html

Comment: That must be the problem. Thank You Very much